# Horizontally scrollable table like div structure

Tags: html, css

I'd like to create a table like div structure, which is placed in a container, can be scrolled horizontally and gets not breaked. I wrote the structure, but when the content gets longer than the container it puts the rest of the content in a new line.

Here's my code so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/rcdzdyv7/2/

where all of these elements represent a "table" row:

```
<div class="header">...</div>
<div class="body">...</div>
<div class="footer">...</div>
```

My goal is to make these rows one-lined and look like if it was a table. How could I solve this?

Comment: Why not just use a table? They exist for a reason... Otherwise you might want to read this: http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/getting_your_di

Comment: probably I'll have to make it possible to fix the first column, and it sounds easier to me to get it done with divs. Thanks for the article :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `float:left` because when content reach the width there's no way to avoid the floating elements "jumping" to next line (without changing the html structure).

However you can use `display:inline-block`becuase your elements this way can change their behaviour with the property `white-space:nowrap`.

Basically:

```
    .container {
        width: 500px;
        overflow-x: scroll;
    }
    .header {
        width: auto;
        display:inline-block;
        background-color: #D9D9D9;
        white-space: nowrap;
        clear: both;
    }
    .body {
        display:inline-block;
        margin: 5px 0;
    }

    .body-row {
        background-color: #E5EBFF;
        display:inline-block;
        clear: both;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .footer {
        clear: both;
        background-color: #D9D9D9;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .row-title {
        width: 300px;
        display:inline-block;
    }
    .row-content {
        width: 150px;
        display:inline-block;
    }
    .value {            
        width: 100%;
    }
```

as in this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rcdzdyv7/4/)**

Comment: You're wellcome. Glad I could help. Gl with your project

Answer (score 3):

You could use:

```
.row-content {
   width: 150px;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

instead of:

```
.row-content {
   width: 150px;
   float: left;
}
```

Let me know if it works!

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you! I accepted the other answer as it was more explained and fixed all my css code, otherwise this answer would have been accepted.

Answer (score 2):

this is because you are using DIV with delimited width no set height.
so when the width needed will be too high for the container width it will automatically do under. Hope this makes sense. A soluation can be to use inline-block, personnally I would recomment to use a classic table but just my opinion

Answer (score 0):

try these css properties to the `<div>` for which you want a scroll

```
div {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

hope this is what you want !